# Adversarial Autoencoder is not working and not learning properly

Tags: python, keras, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to get an Adversarial AutoEncoder going using keras Fit method on a keras.model class
but for some reason it is not working.

Keep in mind that I tried updating encoder and decoder at the same time.
I tried giving the disc loss to the encoder with and without the reconstruction loss

The reconstruction loss stayed the same while encoder disc loss kept increasing as the discriminator's own loss kept dropping.

```
discriminator = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(4, 4, 128)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
        layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"),
    ],
    name="discriminator",
)
discriminator.summary()
encoder  = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(28, 28, 1)),
        layers.Conv2D(24, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.Conv2D(48, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.Conv2D(96, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(4 * 4 * 128, activation="linear"),
        layers.Reshape((4, 4, 128)),
    ],
    name="encoder",
)
encoder.summary()

decoder  = keras.Sequential(
    [
        keras.Input(shape=(4, 4, 128)),
        layers.Flatten(),
        layers.Dense(7 * 7 * 64, activation="relu"),
        layers.Reshape((7, 7, 64)),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, 3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same"),
        layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, 3, activation="sigmoid", strides=1, padding="same"),

    ],
    name="decoder",
)
```

I am not sure If it is in the model itself of not. I am using MNIST Dataset for this

```
class AAE(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, discriminator):
        super(AAE, self).__init__()
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.discriminator = discriminator

        self.total_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="total_loss")
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="reconstruction_loss")
        self.disc_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="disc_loss")
        self.discEnc_tracker = keras.metrics.Mean(name="discEnc_loss")
        
    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [
            self.total_loss_tracker,
            self.reconstruction_loss_tracker,
            self.disc_tracker,
            self.discEnc_tracker,
        ]


    def compile(self, di_optimizer, e_optimizer,de_optimizer, loss_fn):
        super(AAE, self).compile()
        self.dis_optimizer = di_optimizer
        self.e_optimizer = e_optimizer
        self.de_optimizer = de_optimizer
        
        self.lossBCE = loss_fn[0]
        self.lossMAE = loss_fn[1]
    

    def train_step(self, data):
        latent = self.encoder(data)
        batch_size = 200
        dists = tf.random.normal((batch_size,4,4,128))

        y_real = tf.ones((batch_size, 1))
        y_fake = tf.zeros((batch_size, 1))
        real_dist_mix = tf.concat((dists, latent),axis=0)
        y_real_fake_mix = tf.concat((y_real, y_fake),axis=0)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            predictions = self.discriminator(real_dist_mix)
            
            d_loss = self.lossBCE(y_real_fake_mix, predictions)
            
        grads = tape.gradient(d_loss, self.discriminator.trainable_weights)
        self.dis_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.discriminator.trainable_weights))

        with tf.GradientTape() as Etape, tf.GradientTape() as Dtape:
            latent = self.encoder(data)
            reconstruction = self.decoder(latent)
            reconstruction_loss = self.lossMAE(data, reconstruction) 
            

            total_loss = reconstruction_loss
        Egrads = Etape.gradient(total_loss, self.encoder.trainable_weights)
        self.e_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(Egrads, self.encoder.trainable_weights))

        Dgrads = Dtape.gradient(total_loss, self.decoder.trainable_weights)
        self.de_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(Dgrads, self.decoder.trainable_weights))


        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            latent = self.encoder(data)
            predictions = self.discriminator(latent)
            e_loss = self.lossBCE(y_fake, predictions)

        grads = tape.gradient(e_loss, self.encoder.trainable_weights)
        self.e_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.encoder.trainable_weights))

        self.total_loss_tracker.update_state(total_loss)
        self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.update_state(reconstruction_loss)
        self.disc_tracker.update_state(d_loss)
        self.discEnc_tracker.update_state(e_loss)
        return {
            "loss": self.total_loss_tracker.result(),
            "reconstruction_loss": self.reconstruction_loss_tracker.result(),
            "disc_loss": self.disc_tracker.result(),
            "discEnc_loss": self.discEnc_tracker.result(),
        }
```

```
(x_train, _), (x_test, _) = keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()
mnist_digits = np.concatenate([x_train, x_test], axis=0)
mnist_digits = np.expand_dims(mnist_digits, -1).astype("float32") / 255

Aae = AAE(encoder, decoder, discriminator)
#vae.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam())
Aae.compile(
    di_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001),
    e_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    de_optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
    loss_fn=[tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),tf.keras.losses.MeanAbsoluteError()]
)
h=Aae.fit(mnist_digits, epochs=15, batch_size=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the error is here:

```
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        latent = self.encoder(data)
        predictions = self.discriminator(latent)
        e_loss = self.lossBCE(y_fake, predictions)

    grads = tape.gradient(e_loss, self.encoder.trainable_weights)
    self.e_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, self.encoder.trainable_weights))
```

I would put `e_loss = self.lossBCE(y_real, predictions)`, because the encoder tries to fool the discriminator.